# Disable 'Crippled Lapack' warning in RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I'm using RcppArmadillo to solve a linear system. The R binary for Macs from CRAN is configured to use a built-in subset of BLAS and Lapack, and I have not been successful in building R to use an external BLAS + Lapack (I sent an email to r-sig-mac for help, but so far haven't received any answer).

Unfortunately, in addition to a possible lack in performance, every time I run the code I'm greeted with a low-level warning,

```
warning: solve(): refinement and/or equilibration not done due to crippled LAPACK
```

which quickly fills my terminal console (I'm running this in a loop). How can I configure RcppArmadillo to not issue this warning?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 Patched (2016-06-05 r70718)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.4 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8/C/en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RcppArmadillo_0.7.200.1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.0 Rcpp_0.12.5
```

Comment: OS X CRAN R comes with both its default BLAS, plus the ability to use OS X's Accelerate BLAS, though the documentation for switching doesn't seem to exist aside from [this](http://www.inside-r.org/questions/switching-between-r-blas-os-x) and [the R admin page](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#LAPACK). The latter suggests that Accelerate uses its own LAPACK, which may fix your problem? If all this sounds obvious or stupid, please ignore me; I'm just about out of my depth.

Comment: Yes, I came across those references too. I used the soft link trick to switch BLAS to Accelerate, which provides substantial speed gains, but it doesn't solve this particular problem with Lapack. And compiling R on a Mac has proven a hopeless task for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `configure` when you install it; check the test output. The code (minus some comments) essentially is:

```
## external LAPACK has the required function
lapack=$(${R_HOME}/bin/R CMD config LAPACK_LIBS)
hasRlapack=$(echo ${lapack} | grep lRlapack)

if [ "${hasRlapack}" == "" ]; then
    ## We are using a full Lapack and can use zgesdd -- so #undef remains
    echo "system LAPACK found"
    cp inst/include/RcppArmadilloLapack.h.in inst/include/RcppArmadilloLapack.h 
else
    ## We are using a R's subset of Lapack and CANNOT use zgesdd etc, so we mark it
    echo "R-supplied partial LAPACK found"
    echo "* some operations may not be available"
    sed -e 's/\/\/ \#undef ARMA_CRIPPLED_LAPACK/\#define ARMA_CRIPPLED_LAPACK 1/' \
        inst/include/RcppArmadilloLapack.h.in > inst/include/RcppArmadilloLapack.h 
fi
```

So in a nutshell you have two options:

i) have a real external LAPACK or

ii) use an R version that has a non-crippled LAPACK bundled -- ie R 3.3.0.

*Edit on 12-Mar-2016:* So there was a bug in that R 3.3.0 was not recognized properly in the case of not having a system LAPACK -- ie OS X as poor Windoze is handled differently anyway.  This is now taken care of in the GH repo.  Thanks to @baptiste for spotting it.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that ii) was my first idea too, but does not seem to help. I've installed R-devel, re-installed RcppArmadillo from source,  and the same warning persists. I'll trying playing with the configure script.

Comment: Do the above by hand, ensure that `ARMA_CRIPPLED_LAPACK` is not set.  Maybe my test needs an update...  Actually, come to think about it might.  And you testing that is just timely.  There is some older stuff there which reflects a version. I *think* we can just give R 3.3.0 or later a pass.

Comment: OK, so I went brute-force because nothing seemed to work. I grep'ed `ARMA_CRIPPLED_LAPACK` and everywhere where I had any doubt it might be defined (I don't know the first thing about those macros) I either commented it, removed it, or set it to 0. It looked like nothing had changed, until I also re-built my own package after RcppArmadillo, and now the warning's final gone. Thanks.

Comment: It's simple: When you do not need the warning (ie system LAPACK, probably R 3.3.0) then copying `RcppArmadilloLapack.h.in` to `RcppArmadilloLapack.h` is sufficient and nothing is defined: the definition is behind a `//` and is just a comment.   But in the other case we transform the `...h.in` but removing the comment and defining it.  So all I wanted you to do is to test the former case.  I'll follow up by email.

Comment: The message is back. Are you sure [this test for R version works?](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/configure#L2744). I have the latest R patched, and just updated RcppArmadillo from CRAN.

Comment: I also cloned the latest RcppArmadillo from github, for which configure finds "fallback LAPACK from R 3.3.0 or later used". But I still get that solve() warning.

Comment: All the relevant code is in `configure.ac`. I would welcome debugging help from your end (as I don't have OS X available to me) on why _e.g._ the value of `newR` (the test for R 3.3.0 or later) could possibly be false.

Comment: I don't really know how to debug this, the configure.ac file is a foreign syntax to me. The message "fallback LAPACK from R 3.3.0 or later used" during compilation would suggest that the newR is set correctly, but then I don't understand why the wrong path is taken further down the line.

Comment: so, I tried replacing `have_good_lapack="#define"` by `have_good_lapack="#undef"` and that got rid off the warning. Is it possible that the configure logic is negated somewhere?

Comment: Please try your best at debugging this.  Configure is really just a shell script portion wrapped,  ditto with the included R code.  If you want this fixed for good please try to help.  I have no system like yours.

Comment: And is case that was unclear,  read/edit `configure.ac` then call `autoconf` to generate `configure`.

Comment: Ie you want to examine [these few lines in `configure.ac`](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/configure.ac#L54-L82) on your box.

Comment: I would, if I didn't have one month left to finish my academic career. Those lines in configure(.ac) immediately raise at least 10 questions in my head, which I would not be able to answer without days of studying things that are not in my priority list. So I'll go with the workaround I described in my email. For whatever reason, it brings back the quiet, and lets me work on my package toward its probable last CRAN update.

Comment: Well, it is somewhat frustrating trying to help you as this is the n-th time you decline to actually step up and try to work with me on solving these issues (which by and large only you report as nobody else uses complex functions and/or uses them on OS X).  Anyway, I won't work on this anymore without a means of testing it so if you don't help, nothing will change.

Comment: f memory serves I did work with you last time (and on other occasions -- I do try my best, sorry if it's not good enough). This time around the code has changed completely (and is harder for me to understand), but it appears that the `#define` macro is working the opposite way of what's expected in the case R>=3.3.0. That's to say, it produces `#define ARMA_CRIPPLED_LAPACK 1` when it should probably do `#undef ARMA_CRIPPLED_LAPACK`. That's my current diagnostics, and it would seem like a trivial thing to assess regardless of the OS (or complex functions for that matter).

Comment: The `#define` is placed after an `if` test. We need to find out why it could be wrong for you when it (apparently) isn't for anybody else.  I can't do that as I do not have OS X.  You flunk this very question by just overriding the outcome.  Anyway we both wasted (way) too much time on this already.

Comment: So if I disable (comment-out) the first test in [lines 64 to 69 (plus the matching `fi` on line 82)](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/configure.ac#L64-L69), rerun `autoconf` and call the new `configure` I get: `checking LAPACK_LIBS... fallback LAPACK from R 3.3.0 or later used`.  And I then see that indeed I have the logic wrong in the assignment. The two variables are the wrong way.  Dang.

Comment: Issue opened, branch created, proposed fix committed and pushed. It's late where I am currently so that'll be it for today.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll test this later today, and report on github.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the brown-bag bug I put there.  We need a unit test for one of the post-R 3.3.0 complex-valued decomposition functions.  Would be great if you could cook one at some point (ie that is not urgent).

Comment: i'll be unemployed soon enough, plenty of time then :)